# FatFs read/write in root work but not in subfolder

Tags: c, file, directory, fatfs

Already thanks for your time.

I'm a little lost on how can I debug a problem I have with FatFs:
write then read files inside folder brings me invalid data.  but on the root, it work flawessly.

note:

- I'm working on a bar-metal nrf52832 using FatFs 14.
- The nrf52832 talk on spi to an external flash MX25L32 (4Mb, 512b/sector, 4096/block)
- I have disabled the relative file path, so I use only absolute path.

  - (I'll join "ffconf.h")

I have the following problem :

- If I write then read a file on the root, it work flawlessly (tested with 10k file)
- If I write then read a file in a subfolder I read somethings strange (even with small file).

and here's the code that I use (cb_littlecodethatfail is called via an RTT terminal):

```
bool debug_write_read(const char * pathFile)
{
    const char will_be_written[] = "this little text should be readen back";
    char is_read_from_file[256]={0};
    FIL fil;

    unsigned int unused;



    // write inside the file ....
    FRESULT res = f_open(&fil, pathFile , FA_WRITE|FA_CREATE_ALWAYS);
    if(res==FR_OK)
    {
        res = f_write(&fil,will_be_written ,sizeof(will_be_written),&unused );
        printf("\tf_write action[%d] : %d\n",unused, res);
        f_close(&fil);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\tcouldn'write'\n");
        return false;
    }

    // read back the file  ....
    res = f_open(&fil, pathFile , FA_READ);
    if(res==FR_OK)
    {
        res = f_read(&fil, is_read_from_file, sizeof(will_be_written),&unused );
        printf("\tf_read action[%d] : %d\n",unused, res);
        f_close(&fil);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\tcouldn'write'\n");
        return false;
    }

    printf("\tread back content :\"%s\"\n",is_read_from_file);
    printf("\tthe first 4 char are in hex : %02x %02x %02x %02x\n",is_read_from_file[0],is_read_from_file[1],is_read_from_file[2],is_read_from_file[3]  );

    return (strcmp(will_be_written,is_read_from_file ) ==0);


}

errCode cb_littlecodethatfail(char * written, int w )
{
// STEP 1 :: format the external flash
    MKFS_PARM opt ={0};
    opt.fmt    = FM_FAT;/* Format option (FM_FAT, FM_FAT32, FM_EXFAT and FM_SFD) */
    opt.n_fat  = 0;     /* Number of FATs   (copies ? ) */
    opt.n_root = 512;     /* Number of root directory entries */
    opt.au_size = 512;      /* Cluster size (byte) */

    BYTE work[FF_MAX_SS]; /* Work area (larger is better for processing time) */
    printf(" start formatting the drive .... \n" );
    FRESULT error = f_mkfs(getDriveName(FLASH_DRIVE), &opt, work, sizeof( work ) );
    if(error!=0)
    {
        printf("Failed to format the drive !!!!! %d \n", error);
    }
    if( f_mount(&fileSystem, getDriveName( FLASH_DRIVE), 1)  != FR_OK )
    {
        printf(" an error occured !!! \n");
        while(1);
    }

    error = f_mkdir("0:/BTLDR");
    if(error!=0)
    {
        printf("Failed to create the working region  %d \n", error);
    }
// STEP 2 :: on the root folder it work no problemo
    printf("test file FOO.BAR on root : \n");
    printf("on root it %s\n", ((debug_write_read("0:FOO.BAR"))?"worked":"didn't worked") );

// STEP 3 :: on the root folder it work no problemo
    printf("test file FOO.BAR on BTLDR folder : \n");
    printf("on folder it %s\n", ((debug_write_read("0:BTLDR/FOO.BAR"))?"worked":"didn't worked") );

// STEP 4 :: on the root folder it work no problemo
    printf("test file FOO_2.BAR on root : \n");
    printf("on root it %s\n", ((debug_write_read("0:FOO_2.BAR"))?"worked":"didn't worked") );
// STEP 3 :: on the root folder it work no problemo
    printf("test file FOO_2.BAR on BTLDR folder : \n");
    printf("on folder it %s\n", ((debug_write_read("0:BTLDR/FOO_2.BAR"))?"worked":"didn't worked") );
    return ERR_NO;
}
```

Here is my "ffconf.h"

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------/
/  FatFs Functional Configurations
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define FFCONF_DEF  86606   /* Revision ID */

/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------/
/ Function Configurations
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define FF_FS_READONLY  0
/* This option switches read-only configuration. (0:Read/Write or 1:Read-only)
/  Read-only configuration removes writing API functions, f_write(), f_sync(),
/  f_unlink(), f_mkdir(), f_chmod(), f_rename(), f_truncate(), f_getfree()
/  and optional writing functions as well. */


#define FF_FS_MINIMIZE  0
/* This option defines minimization level to remove some basic API functions.
/
/   0: Basic functions are fully enabled.
/   1: f_stat(), f_getfree(), f_unlink(), f_mkdir(), f_truncate() and f_rename()
/      are removed.
/   2: f_opendir(), f_readdir() and f_closedir() are removed in addition to 1.
/   3: f_lseek() function is removed in addition to 2. */


#define FF_USE_STRFUNC  0
/* This option switches string functions, f_gets(), f_putc(), f_puts() and f_printf().
/
/  0: Disable string functions.
/  1: Enable without LF-CRLF conversion.
/  2: Enable with LF-CRLF conversion. */


#define FF_USE_FIND     0
/* This option switches filtered directory read functions, f_findfirst() and
/  f_findnext(). (0:Disable, 1:Enable 2:Enable with matching altname[] too) */


#define FF_USE_MKFS     1
/* This option switches f_mkfs() function. (0:Disable or 1:Enable) */


#define FF_USE_FASTSEEK 0
/* This option switches fast seek function. (0:Disable or 1:Enable) */


#define FF_USE_EXPAND   0
/* This option switches f_expand function. (0:Disable or 1:Enable) */


#define FF_USE_CHMOD    0
/* This option switches attribute manipulation functions, f_chmod() and f_utime().
/  (0:Disable or 1:Enable) Also FF_FS_READONLY needs to be 0 to enable this option. */


#define FF_USE_LABEL    0
/* This option switches volume label functions, f_getlabel() and f_setlabel().
/  (0:Disable or 1:Enable) */


#define FF_USE_FORWARD  0
/* This option switches f_forward() function. (0:Disable or 1:Enable) */


/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------/
/ Locale and Namespace Configurations
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define FF_CODE_PAGE    437
/* This option specifies the OEM code page to be used on the target system.
/  Incorrect code page setting can cause a file open failure.
/
/   437 - U.S.
/   720 - Arabic
/   737 - Greek
/   771 - KBL
/   775 - Baltic
/   850 - Latin 1
/   852 - Latin 2
/   855 - Cyrillic
/   857 - Turkish
/   860 - Portuguese
/   861 - Icelandic
/   862 - Hebrew
/   863 - Canadian French
/   864 - Arabic
/   865 - Nordic
/   866 - Russian
/   869 - Greek 2
/   932 - Japanese (DBCS)
/   936 - Simplified Chinese (DBCS)
/   949 - Korean (DBCS)
/   950 - Traditional Chinese (DBCS)
/     0 - Include all code pages above and configured by f_setcp()
*/


#define FF_USE_LFN      0   // only canonic 8.3 (3lettre ext and 8char long name) bit file name are ok :)
#define FF_MAX_LFN      255
/* The FF_USE_LFN switches the support for LFN (long file name).
/
/   0: Disable LFN. FF_MAX_LFN has no effect.
/   1: Enable LFN with static  working buffer on the BSS. Always NOT thread-safe.
/   2: Enable LFN with dynamic working buffer on the STACK.
/   3: Enable LFN with dynamic working buffer on the HEAP.
/
/  To enable the LFN, ffunicode.c needs to be added to the project. The LFN function
/  requiers certain internal working buffer occupies (FF_MAX_LFN + 1) * 2 bytes and
/  additional (FF_MAX_LFN + 44) / 15 * 32 bytes when exFAT is enabled.
/  The FF_MAX_LFN defines size of the working buffer in UTF-16 code unit and it can
/  be in range of 12 to 255. It is recommended to be set it 255 to fully support LFN
/  specification.
/  When use stack for the working buffer, take care on stack overflow. When use heap
/  memory for the working buffer, memory management functions, ff_memalloc() and
/  ff_memfree() exemplified in ffsystem.c, need to be added to the project. */


#define FF_LFN_UNICODE  2
/* This option switches the character encoding on the API when LFN is enabled.
/
/   0: ANSI/OEM in current CP (TCHAR = char)
/   1: Unicode in UTF-16 (TCHAR = WCHAR)
/   2: Unicode in UTF-8 (TCHAR = char)
/   3: Unicode in UTF-32 (TCHAR = DWORD)
/
/  Also behavior of string I/O functions will be affected by this option.
/  When LFN is not enabled, this option has no effect. */


#define FF_LFN_BUF      255
#define FF_SFN_BUF      12
/* This set of options defines size of file name members in the FILINFO structure
/  which is used to read out directory items. These values should be suffcient for
/  the file names to read. The maximum possible length of the read file name depends
/  on character encoding. When LFN is not enabled, these options have no effect. */


#define FF_STRF_ENCODE  3
/* When FF_LFN_UNICODE >= 1 with LFN enabled, string I/O functions, f_gets(),
/  f_putc(), f_puts and f_printf() convert the character encoding in it.
/  This option selects assumption of character encoding ON THE FILE to be
/  read/written via those functions.
/
/   0: ANSI/OEM in current CP
/   1: Unicode in UTF-16LE
/   2: Unicode in UTF-16BE
/   3: Unicode in UTF-8
*/


#define FF_FS_RPATH     0
/* This option configures support for relative path.
/
/   0: Disable relative path and remove related functions.
/   1: Enable relative path. f_chdir() and f_chdrive() are available.
/   2: f_getcwd() function is available in addition to 1.
*/


/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------/
/ Drive/Volume Configurations
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define FF_VOLUMES      1
/* Number of volumes (logical drives) to be used. (1-10) */


#define FF_STR_VOLUME_ID    0
#define FF_VOLUME_STRS      "FLASH", "NONE"
/* FF_STR_VOLUME_ID switches support for volume ID in arbitrary strings.
/  When FF_STR_VOLUME_ID is set to 1 or 2, arbitrary strings can be used as drive
/  number in the path name. FF_VOLUME_STRS defines the volume ID strings for each
/  logical drives. Number of items must not be less than FF_VOLUMES. Valid
/  characters for the volume ID strings are A-Z, a-z and 0-9, however, they are
/  compared in case-insensitive. If FF_STR_VOLUME_ID >= 1 and FF_VOLUME_STRS is
/  not defined, a user defined volume string table needs to be defined as:
/
/  const char* VolumeStr[FF_VOLUMES] = {"ram","flash","sd","usb",...
*/


#define FF_MULTI_PARTITION  0
/* This option switches support for multiple volumes on the physical drive.
/  By default (0), each logical drive number is bound to the same physical drive
/  number and only an FAT volume found on the physical drive will be mounted.
/  When this function is enabled (1), each logical drive number can be bound to
/  arbitrary physical drive and partition listed in the VolToPart[]. Also f_fdisk()
/  funciton will be available. */


#define FF_MIN_SS       512
#define FF_MAX_SS       4096
/* This set of options configures the range of sector size to be supported. (512,
/  1024, 2048 or 4096) Always set both 512 for most systems, generic memory card and
/  harddisk. But a larger value may be required for on-board flash memory and some
/  type of optical media. When FF_MAX_SS is larger than FF_MIN_SS, FatFs is configured
/  for variable sector size mode and disk_ioctl() function needs to implement
/  GET_SECTOR_SIZE command. */


#define FF_LBA64        0
/* This option switches support for 64-bit LBA. (0:Disable or 1:Enable)
/  To enable the 64-bit LBA, also exFAT needs to be enabled. (FF_FS_EXFAT == 1) */


#define FF_MIN_GPT      0x100000000
/* Minimum number of sectors to switch GPT format to create partition in f_mkfs and
/  f_fdisk function. 0x100000000 max. This option has no effect when FF_LBA64 == 0. */


#define FF_USE_TRIM     0
/* This option switches support for ATA-TRIM. (0:Disable or 1:Enable)
/  To enable Trim function, also CTRL_TRIM command should be implemented to the
/  disk_ioctl() function. */



/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------/
/ System Configurations
/---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define FF_FS_TINY      0
/* This option switches tiny buffer configuration. (0:Normal or 1:Tiny)
/  At the tiny configuration, size of file object (FIL) is shrinked FF_MAX_SS bytes.
/  Instead of private sector buffer eliminated from the file object, common sector
/  buffer in the filesystem object (FATFS) is used for the file data transfer. */


#define FF_FS_EXFAT     0
/* This option switches support for exFAT filesystem. (0:Disable or 1:Enable)
/  To enable exFAT, also LFN needs to be enabled. (FF_USE_LFN >= 1)
/  Note that enabling exFAT discards ANSI C (C89) compatibility. */


#define FF_FS_NORTC     0
#define FF_NORTC_MON    1
#define FF_NORTC_MDAY   1
#define FF_NORTC_YEAR   2019
/* The option FF_FS_NORTC switches timestamp functiton. If the system does not have
/  any RTC function or valid timestamp is not needed, set FF_FS_NORTC = 1 to disable
/  the timestamp function. Every object modified by FatFs will have a fixed timestamp
/  defined by FF_NORTC_MON, FF_NORTC_MDAY and FF_NORTC_YEAR in local time.
/  To enable timestamp function (FF_FS_NORTC = 0), get_fattime() function need to be
/  added to the project to read current time form real-time clock. FF_NORTC_MON,
/  FF_NORTC_MDAY and FF_NORTC_YEAR have no effect.
/  These options have no effect in read-only configuration (FF_FS_READONLY = 1). */


#define FF_FS_NOFSINFO  0
/* If you need to know correct free space on the FAT32 volume, set bit 0 of this
/  option, and f_getfree() function at first time after volume mount will force
/  a full FAT scan. Bit 1 controls the use of last allocated cluster number.
/
/  bit0=0: Use free cluster count in the FSINFO if available.
/  bit0=1: Do not trust free cluster count in the FSINFO.
/  bit1=0: Use last allocated cluster number in the FSINFO if available.
/  bit1=1: Do not trust last allocated cluster number in the FSINFO.
*/


#define FF_FS_LOCK      2
/* The option FF_FS_LOCK switches file lock function to control duplicated file open
/  and illegal operation to open objects. This option must be 0 when FF_FS_READONLY
/  is 1.
/
/  0:  Disable file lock function. To avoid volume corruption, application program
/      should avoid illegal open, remove and rename to the open objects.
/  >0: Enable file lock function. The value defines how many files/sub-directories
/      can be opened simultaneously under file lock control. Note that the file
/      lock control is independent of re-entrancy. */


/* #include <somertos.h>    // O/S definitions */
#define FF_FS_REENTRANT 0
#define FF_FS_TIMEOUT   1000
#define FF_SYNC_t       HANDLE
/* The option FF_FS_REENTRANT switches the re-entrancy (thread safe) of the FatFs
/  module itself. Note that regardless of this option, file access to different
/  volume is always re-entrant and volume control functions, f_mount(), f_mkfs()
/  and f_fdisk() function, are always not re-entrant. Only file/directory access
/  to the same volume is under control of this function.
/
/   0: Disable re-entrancy. FF_FS_TIMEOUT and FF_SYNC_t have no effect.
/   1: Enable re-entrancy. Also user provided synchronization handlers,
/      ff_req_grant(), ff_rel_grant(), ff_del_syncobj() and ff_cre_syncobj()
/      function, must be added to the project. Samples are available in
/      option/syscall.c.
/
/  The FF_FS_TIMEOUT defines timeout period in unit of time tick.
/  The FF_SYNC_t defines O/S dependent sync object type. e.g. HANDLE, ID, OS_EVENT*,
/  SemaphoreHandle_t and etc. A header file for O/S definitions needs to be
/  included somewhere in the scope of ff.h. */



/*--- End of configuration options ---*/
```

Here's the output I have

```
 start formatting the drive ....
flashID is 0xC22016
test file FOO.BAR on root :
        f_write action[39] : 0
        f_read action[39] : 0
        read back content :"this little text should be readen back"
        the first 4 char are in hex : 74 68 69 73
on root it worked
test file FOO.BAR on BTLDR folder :
        f_write action[39] : 0
        f_read action[39] : 0
        read back content :"                                       "
        the first 4 char are in hex : FF FF FF FF
on folder it didn't worked
test file FOO_2.BAR on root :
        f_write action[39] : 0
        f_read action[39] : 0
        read back content :"this little text should be readen back"
        the first 4 char are in hex : 74 68 69 73
on root it worked
test file FOO_2.BAR on BTLDR folder :
        f_write action[39] : 0
        f_read action[39] : 0
        read back content :"                                       "
        the first 4 char are in hex : FF FF FF FF
on folder it didn't worked
```

Do you think it can come from an configuration error ?
Do you have any idea on where should I look to find why I have that ?

Have a nice day! and again, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's me again,

The bug is inside the glue 'disk_write' function. As long as block was written in the right order, everythings worked well.   But it's not always the case.

sorry for my noobness, here's the implementation actual of the disk_write

```
DRESULT disk_write(BYTE Drive, /* Physical drive number */
                    const BYTE *Buffer, /* Pointer to the write data (may be non aligned) */
                    DWORD SectorNumber, /* Sector number to write */
                    UINT SectorCount /* Number of sectors to write */
                    )
{
    #define ONE_BLOCKSIZE 0x1000
    DRESULT toret=0;
    uint8_t zeFullblock[ONE_BLOCKSIZE];

    uint32_t size          = SectorCount * FATFS_SECTOR_SIZE;
    uint32_t abs_adrs      = SectorNumber*FATFS_SECTOR_SIZE;


    uint32_t adressBlock = abs_adrs&0xFFFFF000;
    uint32_t latest_adressBlock = (abs_adrs+size-1)&0xFFFFF000;

    uint32_t adressinBlock = abs_adrs-adressBlock;


    if(adressBlock != latest_adressBlock)
    {
        printf("unsupported write multiple block at once \n");
        toret |= RES_ERROR;
        return toret;
    }



    errCode treated = flash_spi_read( adressBlock, (uint8_t*) zeFullblock, ONE_BLOCKSIZE);
    if (treated != ERR_NO) {
        toret |= RES_ERROR;
        return toret;
    }
    flash_spi_erase(adressBlock, ONE_BLOCKSIZE);

    memcpy(&(zeFullblock[adressinBlock]) , Buffer  ,sizeof(uint8_t) * size );

    treated = flash_spi_write(adressBlock, (const uint8_t*) zeFullblock, ONE_BLOCKSIZE);
    if (treated != ERR_NO) {
        toret |= RES_ERROR;
    }

    return toret;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a read/erase/modify/write on the sector you are writting to... I suppose you are using a external flash memory. this answers is base on the minimal information provided!